# Some faces are not rendering properly

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm new to OpenGL and I'm trying to import an OBJ-file for my bachelor thesis.
In principle it is working but unfortunately there is a problem with the faces which
I first saw when using a big obj-file (~15.000 vertices) - some of them don't get rendered properly.
I already tried to fix it with

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

but it didn't work though.

Frustrated by this, I wrote a simple cube model-object file. (see quader.obj in link below)

I tried to import it with my "Load"-function (see ModelObj.h and ModelObj.cpp)
but depending on the object's position, there are some faces missing.

(Images of cube, ModelObj-class and quader.obj all zipped [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xa8gfqtxpgiz6a/ModelObj.zip)).

After loading the vertices, the import by the display function looks like this:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,    0, obj.getFaces());
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, obj.getNormals());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj.getTotalConnTriangles() );
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Note: I also tried rendering the same simple cube "manually" by creating polygons
in my display-function and it worked properly.

So what's/where's the problem?

Comment: `obj.getTotalConnTriangles()` sounds like the wrong function to call, to me. This is a ***triangle list***, thus the number of vertices in a list containing that many triangles is **x3**. You may only be drawing 1/3 of your model because of that.

Comment: thank you very much for helping, but unfortunately this wasn't the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few remarks for your code which can lead to the wrong rendering

> 1. glVertexPointer check that parameters again. I remeber that you need the following parameters.
>
>    size : how many points for one Vertex
>
>    type : of which type the points are (GL_FLOAT for example)
>
>    stride : how many bytes are between one vertex and the next one (interleaved if you store color in the same array)
>
>    pointer : pointer to the first vertex ( if your array looks like xyzxyzxyz then it should be 0)
> 2. Same as for glNormalPointer - Check the parameters

For 1 and 2 I think your obj.getFaces() and obj.getNormals() are wrong

The third thing is your rendering call

> glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj.getTotalConnTriangles() );

As you take a lot of vertices as input you do not say how many triangles but you say how many indicies to render therefore you should say

> obj.getTotalConnTriangles()  *3

Comment: Thank you - first of all.
You were right according to the last point (the triangles).
Though I don't know which param could be wrong. Because obj.getFaces() and obj.getNormals() returns a the two pointers to the members of my ModelObj.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:
well - there wasn't any problem in the rendering process - it was because
of the order of vertexnumbers in the face-definitions.
Usually you need to vertices **clockwise** (imagine topview of triangle)
if you mix them up with counter-clockwise facedefinitions, OpenGL will build the surface on the other side.
HTH